# Using -c copy in ffmpeg to extract wanted frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am currently working on a project to make summary of the surveillance video. The idea is to read frames using OpenCV, do a foreground detection and classify person with deep learning method.

Since encoding with x264 takes huge resources of the CPU, I want to use -c copy in ffmpeg to avoid encoding. I can recognize the indices of the frames that involves moving person, or the corresponding timestamps, is there a way that I can use the copy codec to generate a result video from the source video without transcoding?

Comment: I have searched on the Internet and found a way to split the video with the timestamp and then merge them with concat. However, since the videos were H264 encoded, I don't know how to solve the keyframe problem, is there a way other than that?

Comment: this might help ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/11175851/127971  ), though, I've found the same problem, when slicing up a video in to pieces, when you paste it back together, the video/audio won't smoothly transition into the next piece, probably due to not splitting on keyframes. In order to have smooth video, I had to reencode the whole video. This is more due to how the splitting works, however, and is not a problem with the concatenation per se.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into the methods of using concat

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot just take individual frames of the input video. These frames may be coded in such a way that they reference other frames and require them for decoding. You cannot avoid re-encoding, unless your input video consists of just I-frames.

If you read your video with OpenCV to analyze the required frames, you might as well use OpenCV directly to output the relevant frames as JPG (or similar) images. Later, you may stitch them together as a video with ffmpeg. Or, use the `VideoWriter` class from OpenCV to create the output video on the fly.

Depending on your use case (and I assume this is more of a research project where you use a large set of input videos to train/validate a model), it may be more efficient to first convert every input video to I-frame only video (e.g., using `ffv1` if you want lossless) and then work with that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried the VideoWriter but it takes huge resources of the CPU for encoding in H264 and the time it takes is very long. I don't have a GPU to speed up the encoding process so the only option is to copy from the source video.

Comment: And I just looked into http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment and found that segment may be helpful. But it seems it can only split the videos with fixed time period, is there a way that I can split them with my own configuration? e.g. 00:00:05 to 00:00:10 and 00:00:13 to 00:00:27

Comment: You can use the segment muxer with custom times (see `-segment_times` option) but this will also require keyframes to properly split.